# Django Forms errors using action parameter

Tags: django, django-forms

On the one page i have some content and several forms, so my view looks like this:

```
def mainpageview(request):
  args = {}
  callbackform = CallBackForm
  mailform = Mail
  args.update(csrf(request))
  args['mainpage'] = Main.objects.get(pk=1)
  args['callbackform'] = callbackform
  args['mailform'] = mailform 
  return render (request, 'main/index.html', args)

def mailform(request):
  if request.POST:
    mailform = Mail(request.POST)
      if mailform.is_valid():
        mail = mailform.cleaned_data['email']
        message = "Email: " + mail
        send_mail(...)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/callbackresult/')
      else:
        mailform = Mail()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/', {'mailform':mailform})
    else:
      mailform = Mail(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {mailform:mailform})

def callback(request):
  if request.POST:
    callbackform = CallBackForm(request.POST)
      if callbackform.is_valid():
        name = callbackform.cleaned_data['name']
        phone = callbackform.cleaned_data['phone']
        message = "Name: " + name + "Phone: " + phone
        send_mail(...)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/callbackresult/')
      else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
  else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

This is how looks my forms:

```
class CallBackForm(forms.Form):
  name = forms.CharField()
  phone = forms.CharField()

class Mail(forms.Form):
  email = forms.EmailField()
```

I add action parameter for every form, so this is example of my template:

```
<form action="/mail/" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{error.mailform}}
   {{ mailform }}
   <input type="submit" class="success button" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

Everything works fine, but i can't get how to write form view to show form error(`{{error.mailform}}`). Hope you can help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new form when the form is not valid. The new form contains no data for the current request so of course will not have any errors.

Try this:

```
if request.POST:
    mailform = Mail(request.POST)
    if mailform.is_valid():
        mail = mailform.cleaned_data['email']
        message = "Email: " + mail
        send_mail(...)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/callbackresult/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'mailform':mailform})
else:
    mailform = Mail()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'mailform':mailform})
```

Its also better to use `render()` when returning the form with errors since you are not actually redirecting the user to a different page

Answer (score 0):

I used this way to display error in the frontend. When error you need to pass the form object into template.

```
mailroom = Mail(request.POST)
if mailroom.is_valid():
    # save here.
else:
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'mailroom': mailroom})
```

and in template  `{{ mailform.errors }}` will give you the errors.

Answer (score 0):

django.contrib provide message to these problems.

```
from django.contrib import messages
# then in your form view, take callback form for example
callbackform = CallBackForm(request.POST)
    if callbackform.is_valid():
        messages.success(request,"success")
    else:
        messages.error(request,"error")
# and in the template
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
{% for message in messages %}
<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

by default, django.contrib.messages is in your 'INSTALLED_APPS', if not, you need to check it.